# How to generate "battery low" notification during mobile app testing with ruby script in calabash-android

Tags: android, ruby, interrupt, calabash

I am trying to generate notifications(Battery,chargerconnect,headphone connect,memory card insertion etc.) with my customized ruby step-definitions in calabash-android during automation of mobile apps.
Is there any way to interact with Android OS broadcasts with ruby script so that i can generate interrupts at any point of mob app testing.

Answer (score 0):

**There are no built-in steps for this in Calabash. You should develop your own.**

---

For instance, setting battery level for default Android Emulator (AVD) will look like:

```
Then /^I set battery level to (\d+) percent$/ do |battery_level|
  %x{"{ echo 'open localhost 5554'; sleep 1; echo 'power capacity #{battery_level}'; } | telnet 2>&1"}
end
```